# TODO comments do not appear in Problems as warning of VS Code after using flutter lint

Tags: flutter, dart

Previously, all todo comments used to appear as warning in VS Code but After I added flutter lint package for additional linting, todo disappeared from Problems. Now I have to use search box for finding todo. I couldn't find a linter rule for that except 'flutter_style_todos' which is not what I want. Any way to make it appear again in problems pane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handling of `TODO` comments isn't done by a linter rule.  You instead can control it by setting:

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    todo: info
```

See [Customizing analysis rules](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#customizing-analysis-rules) for other possible values (and which also shows a specific example for configuring handling of `TODO` comments).